# how to draw capital Letters and fill that alphabets by finger using Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, dialog, android-canvas, paint

I am working on app in which I have to draw Letters and I want to draw line by finger. when letter is completely fill then open dialog box that shows that `completed the latter "A"`as shown below picture.

For example I have letters like A as given in picture:[image]

But I want to do like this ,

[image]

if anyone know about this concept then help me...!!!

Comment: did you get any solution??

Comment: No...still not Getiing Any Solution..!!!1

Comment: I got the solution and Thank you for your reply. Cheers !!!

Comment: @Viks can you share your solution?

Comment: @VijayRajput ok i'll share when i got time. You can contact me at facebook.com/viksbaba

Comment: @Viks can you share code?

Comment: @VijayRajput please check below answer